# Batch script - how to find string that start with another string

Tags: batch-file, cmd

In a batch script, I want to move over every line from a text file, and find if it starts with some string (which I don't know the length of it)

```
set _start_string=whatever
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (C:\file.txt) do (
  echo _line=%%a
  if **\_line start with _start_string\** do (echo %_line%)
  )
```

here need to search which `_line` starts with `_start_string`,
only the if the condition is missing.

Comment: you should try to use ```findstr``` and a regex (by creating a regex with your ```_start_string```). Use this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/23170295/20499460 and you can also use https://regex101.com/ to test your regex

Comment: thanks @Thomas, i cant understand where do i put my variables at "echo %node% | findstr /r "[vV][0-9.]*" >nul 2>&1 && (echo contains)" sentence

Comment: Your previous comment suggests that you're not looking for a string in a file, but a regular expression. Something like this single line batch file example: ```@%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /IR "^v\.*[0123456789][0123456789]*" "C:\file.txt" 2>NUL```. Or perhaps: ```@%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /IR "^v[0123456789\.][0123456789]*" "C:\file.txt" 2>NUL```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll explain what I wrote in my comment here.

First the only way to compare a part of a string is by using the `findstr` command. You can use the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/23170295/20499460 if you want or just use the code below (it should work but i can't test it) :

1- remove your if :

```
if **\_line start with _start_string\** do (echo %_line%)
```

2- correct you echo to a set (it looks like a mistake) :

```
set _line=%%a
```

3- change it for the line :

```
echo %%a | findstr /b %_start_string% >nul 2>&1 && (echo %%a)
```

So you print your line : `echo %%a`, search for the string `_start_string` at the start of the line (with the `findstr` and the `/b` option).

AND if everything worked correctly, print the line.

The `>nul 2>&1` is just here to remove all the output of the `findstr` and only keep what is after the `&&`

Hope this helps ! Feel free to ask further questions :)

Comment: thank you @Thomas!! it is working great! now i need to change the if condition for getting line that start with '_start_string' and ends with '_end_string' (if inside if probably), how do i change the existing one?

Comment: Probably something like ``echo %%a | findstr /b %_start_string% >nul 2>&1 && (echo %%a | findstr /e %_end_string% >nul 2>&1 && (echo %%a))`` (just replace the ``echo %%a`` by all the line). In ``findstr`` the ``/b`` is for the start of the line and the ``/e`` for the end. If you try both in a row it should check if the line accept both of your strings. Don't forget to accept this answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: the ending string didnt working, even when i try it separately : `echo %%a | findstr /e %_end_string% >nul 2>&1 && (echo %%a)`

Comment: @rotem show your code (edit your question) and add an exemple of a line your testing. I can't continue to help you without more informations :)

Comment: it's working!! i just needed to delete the spaces between from `%%a | findstr`  to `%%a|findstr` and it's works! thanks a lot @Thomas MONTIGNY !!

Comment: well done ! don't forget to update your question to show us the result and help the next users :)

Answer (score 0):

```
findstr /b /L /c:"%_start_string%"
```

would find those lines for you. You make no mention of `_start_string` being a regex.